# How to create one to many relationships in neo4j graph in most efficient way?

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-cql

I am currently new to neo4j and exploring with cypher queries for a task at hand. I am using neo4j bolt driver in Java
Here is what I am trying to achieve. I have something like below data available as a Java ArrayList(stored in a HashMap):

employerId 2 : [employeeId 1, employeeId 2, employeeId3, ...]

Which basically shows relationship between employer and employee (these are the employees of employer 2)

Now, I need to find these employees & employer in the graph(they may or may not exist already) and create a **"(x:Employer) -[Employs]->(y:Employee)"** relationship between them.

One way (maybe, naive) that I can think of, is to search for employer and employee every time and run a separate CREATE query for each.

```
match (employer:Employer{name:"John"}), (name:Employee{name:"Snow"}) CREATE (employer)-[pr:EMPLOYES]->(employee)
```

But I feel that it would unnecessary search for the same Employer node multiple times. And as time is an important criterion for me right now, I am looking for a better way(if exists)

As a newbie to neo4j, all I can think of is, to do a search for the employer ID once, and then run multiple queries using that result, with Employee ID being searched every time. But I am unable to find the correct query to do this. Moreover, will this be the right approach? I need to prepare this query from Java. So should I query multiple times or send a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query below looks similar to the one from @Lju. However, it has a few improvements.

1. The `MERGE` for the `Employer` only needs to be done once, so it should come before the `UNWIND`. Otherwise, it would be done for every `Employee`.
2. You should pass the employer name (or id) and the list of employee
   names (or ids) in
   [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/). In
   the following example, the Cypher code refers to the parameters as
   `$employerName` and `$names`.
3. Also, since the `WITH` clause between the 2 `MERGE` clauses was just passing all identifiers forward, it is not needed. (However, Cypher syntax does require a `WITH` clause between a `MERGE` and an `UNWIND`).

Query:

```
MERGE (employer:Employer {name: $employerName})
WITH employer
UNWIND $names AS name
MERGE (employee:Employee {name: name})
MERGE (employer)-[:Employs]->(employee)
RETURN *
```

Comment: Works perfectly well, and does the job. Will benchmark it to see if it helps with the performance as well. (looks like it should)
Marking the answer as accepted.